# My webview video is continously loading, how do I get it to play?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, webview, youtube

I'm having some trouble trying to get this video playing in my webview. The youtube video appears but whenever I attempt to play the video, all it does is continuously load. How do I fix this? Also, I have the hardware acceleration on true. Here's my current code for playing the video:

```
String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/_4IRMYuE1hI\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The youtube video appears but whenever I attempt to play the video,
>   all it does is continuously load. How do I fix this?

I had the same issue, on a real device (emulator won't work AFAIK). In order to fix that, you need to enable the hardware acceleration for your app. You can enable it by adding:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml file. E.g:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Comment: I've already tried that out and it still doesn't work. I'm testing it on an emulator, could that be the reason why?

Comment: Thanks. The emulator was the problem. Tested it on my device and it's working perfectly!